# Print status of database table

Tags: mysql, django

I need to print the current status of db table as the db sees it (not what the models think it is).

I'm using Django 1.8. And MySQL.

For example, https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23505 shows a status of a table at the bottom. How'd that happen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you probably want to use `DESCRIBE tablename`; you can get more information about ways to inspect your database in [the official docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-information.html).

Note that other databases will use other methods; Django itself is database-agnostic.

Comment: Thank you! That got me some of the info I need. But I'm after the Indexes and unique constraint info as well.

Comment: Read the documentation I linked: "If you have indexes on a table, SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name produces information about them"